# ArcGIS Java Configuration Tool (JCT) Error: could not creat a registry key

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, java, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to select debugging options in the Java Configuration Tool, ArcGIS Desktop 10.5. I have done this before, many times, in 10.4.
But now, in 10.5 on a new computer, I am getting this message:

"Error: could not creat a registry key."

The error message appears no matter which checkbox I select. All 3 options produce the error pop-up.

How do I handle this error?

[image: JVM]

The JCT is found in ArcGIS\Desktop10.X\bin

See link for more:

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/#5ea8aa1a-0b3e-46c1-8589-757bdc50d4d1.htm

Answer (score 0):

Turns out "Run as administrator" is the answer.

Right-click on the Java Configuration Tool in ArcGIS\Desktop10.X\bin and select "Run as administrator."

[image]